# low level keyboard input more lower than keybd_event

Tags: c#, winforms

Now I'm making a macro program using c# Winform for game.

I'm using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

But it doesn't work in game.

Is there no lower level than keybd_event same as real keyboard input?

Comment: Please add a complete example of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work in game"? What are you expecting to happen and what does or doesn't actually happen? Do you get an error, have you tried debugging, ...?

Comment: No errors in my code. Now I'm trying to make a macro program for "LDPlayer" but is doesn't work.(Nothing happened when I run the code.) So I need more powerful and  lower keyboard simulate function.

Comment: My code is working at Notepad, but it didn't working at "LDPlayer". I think LDPlayer blocked keyboard simulate.